# How can I fix an Image error with GUIzero on Python

Tags: python, image, user-interface

I'm a beginner in Python and I was wondering why my "app" wont display my image but it'll display everything else fine.  I'm using GUIzero.  Image file is in the same folder as the code file.

Error: Traceback  ***GUIZERO ERROR***
Image import error - ‘couldn’t
recognize data in image file “lad.png”
Check the file path and image type is GIF/PNG

Here's my code ↓

```
from guizero import App, Text, Picture
app = App("Wanted!")
app.bg = "#FFFBB0"
wanted_text = Text(app, "WANTED")
wanted_text.text_size = 50
wanted_text.font = "Times New Roman"
cat = Picture(app, image="lad.png")
app.display()
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you get error message when you run in console/terminal? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") inquestion (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: are you sure that lad.png is a valid png? If you are using Linux, you can check with e.g. `file lad.png`

Comment: Yes, "lad.png" is a png

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and then I changed my Image file and downloaded a new png file from the internet and put it in the same folder in which my program was.. and boom magic happened and my program run well.
the first image was actually a jpg image and I converted it into png using an online converter I think it doesn't converted well into png.